# In Factual how to get results with unique field values (similar to GROUP BY in SQL)?

Tags: factual

I've just set out on the path to discovery of [Factual API](http://developer.factual.com/api-docs/) and I cannot see how to achieve a retrieval of a selection of entries each with a unique value in the specified field.

For example, give me 10 results from various **cities**:

```
q.limit(10);
q.field("locality").unique();  // no such filter exists
factual.fetch("places", q);
```

This would be an equivalent query in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM places GROUP BY locality LIMIT 10;
```

What I want is a little bit similar to facets:

```
FacetQuery fq = new FacetQuery("locality").maxValuesPerFacet(10);
fq.field("country").isEqual("gb");
FacetResponse resp = factual.fetch("places", fq);
```

but instead of the total for each result I would like to see a random object with all the information.

Is anything like this possible?